# Is it correct to say "building a bathroom fixture", meaning with several toilets?

Tags: phrase-request

I'm searching for the correct term to say that I'm going to build a bathroom, by bathroom I don't mean a single bathroom in a house but the kind you see in a school or a mall (several toilets and urinals). I am also unsure if it's good to use the word "fixture" in the phrase.

Comment: Thanks for accepting, but please consider [waiting longer](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1307/not-so-fast-when-should-i-accept-my-answer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the US, you'd called it a *restroom*, or to be specific, a ***public restroom***. *Public bathroom* is also possible. The Wikipedia article on the matter says that it has a variety of names across the many English speaking regions:

> ### [Public Toilet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_toilet)
>
> A public toilet is a room or small building containing one or more toilets (and possibly also urinals) which is available for use by the general public, or by customers or employees of certain businesses. Public toilets are commonly separated into male and female facilities, although some can be unisex, particularly the smaller or single-occupancy types. Increasingly, public toilets are accessible to people with disabilities.
>
> #### Terminology
>
> ... In American English, "restroom" usually denotes a toilet facility designed for use by the public. However, "bathroom" is also commonly used. "Comfort station" sometimes refers to a visitor welcome center such as those found in national parks.
>
> In Canadian English, public facilities are always called "washrooms". The word "toilet" generally denotes the fixture itself rather than the room. The word "washroom" is never used to mean "utility room" or "mud room" as it is in some parts the United States. "Bathroom" is generally used to refer to the room in the home that contains a bath or shower.
>
> In Britain, Australia, Hong Kong, Singapore, and New Zealand, the terms in use are "public toilet", "public lavatory" (abbreviated "lav") and more informally, "public loo". A "bathroom" is a room containing a bath, a "washroom" is a room for washing hands, and a "restroom" is a room to rest in when tired; none of which would necessarily contain a toilet. As public toilets were traditionally signed as "Gentlemen" or "Ladies", the colloquial terms "the Gents" and "the Ladies" indicates the facility itself. The British Toilet Association, sponsor of the Loo of the Year Award, refers to public toilets collectively as "away from home" toilets.

This phrase, however, does not imply that it is a restroom with multiple toilets and urinals. I don't know if there is an exact phrase, but I have seen some results online for *multi-user/single-user restrooms* and *multiple-user restrooms*. I also found [this pdf](http://www.phlush.org/wp-content/uploads/2009/01/single-user-vs-multi-user.pdf) from phlush.org that calls it a "gang toilet":

> A  multi-user toilet room , or a “gang toilet”, is any restroom shared by strangers  out of public view.

I'm not sure how common that is.

No, you would not say that you are building bathroom fixtures because that would mean that you build the fixed "parts", like the toilet, the stall, the sink, etc. (You can read more about restroom fixtures [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_toilet#Fixtures), on the same Wikipedia page.) I assume that you mean that you purchased those things and want to assemble them into a restroom. So you would say "I am building a (public) restroom" or "I build (public) restrooms".

Answer (score 0):

A proper term to use would be *bathroom facilities* because it implies not just the toilet, but the sink, the door, the individual restrooms, lighting and all the other miscellany that goes into making public bathrooms.

> I am the primary contractor responsible for all bathroom facilities at this location.